# How to automatically update divs height based on other div height?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have following setup:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
   <div id="first"> 
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
   <div id="second">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In which, div with id `first` has `height` property set to `auto`. I want to be able to automatically detect change in height of the div with id `first`, and set height of div with id `second` to `x-70px` where `x` is height of div `first`.

How can I do this?

Comment: determine the event, function, etc that change it's height and add @Wowsk answer there. `$("#second").height($("#first").height());`

Answer (score 1):

Set the second div's height to the first div's height with jQuery.

```
$("#second").height($("#first").height());
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to update when height of first div changes.

Comment: how are you changing the height of the first div? Do you have a live example?

Comment: It changes automatically ,based on number of elements displayed in it.

Comment: @uksz Then you put Wowsk code in the routine that add or delete elements...

Comment: use css flex property